# dynamically allocated arrays with user input c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to have a mini function that allows the user to type a group of numbers, and each of them will be dynamically allocated into an array. For example:

```
int main()
{
    int* x = NULL;
    int n, numbers;
    std::cin >> n;
    x = new int[n]
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        std::cin >> numbers;
        x[i] = numbers;
    }

delete [] x;
```

So when the user types in

```
3
```

The user will be able to type in 3 numbers following that

```
3 1 2 3
```

I am trying to store the values 1, 2, 3 into an array so it will look like

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

but right now it's storing as

```
[123]
```

Anyway i can fix this? I'm new to C++ programming so I feel like there's an easy solution to this but i'm not sure how.. thank you!

Comment: When using cin you need to press enter for each entry. For instance: 1 <enter> 2 <enter> , etc

Comment: @Pedrom That is incorrect.

Comment: What do you mean it's storing it as [123] instead of [1,2,3]?

Comment: @ZacHowland No, it is correct, you need to include a blank separator in order to cin separate the items. Enter key works well for me but an space would do the trick too

Comment: @Pedrom _'you need to include a blank separator in order to cin separate the items.'_ Aha! Was that being asked for??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Since his code works fine I am assuming he is entering the input incorrectly. If that is the case then yes... it is was what asked...

Comment: @Pedrom Yes, agreed, it's simply unclear ...

Comment: @Pedrom `ENTER` is not the only separator.  You do not need to press enter between each entry - a space will do fine.  Typing the input `3 1 2 3` (which is what the OP stated she did), works and does not need to be changed to `3 <enter> 1 <enter> 2 <enter> 3 <enter>`.

Answer (score 2):

You could store each element of the array directly into x[i]. Not sure what numbers is used for (I've assigned numbers from x[i]).

x is the array that is to be deleted. And there is a missing  `;` at `x = new int[x]` - is that a typo?

```
int main()
{
    int* x = NULL;
    int n, numbers;
    std::cin >> n;
    x = new int[n];
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        std::cin >> x[i];
        numbers = x[i];
    }

delete [] x;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `vector` instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    vector<int> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        int val;
        cin >> val;

        v.push_back(val);
    }
}
```

C++'s `vector` takes care of memory allocation for you. You could then simply traverse it and print its contents.

```
cout << "[";
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
{
    if (i != 0)
        cout << ",";
    cout << v[i];
}
cout << "]";
```

Comment: "C++'s vector takes care of memory allocation for you." Correct, which is why it is not necessary to ask for the size of the vector (`n`).

Comment: @JorenHeit Its not about the vector size but the amount of numbers the user wants to enter.

Comment: @FrançoisMoisan Why would you want to know that? That's what `CTRL+D` (EOF) is for, right?

Comment: @JorenHeit Sure, but its unclear if that is a requirement for OP's task (asking for count explicitly) or if he just did it to allocate the array.

Comment: @FrançoisMoisan As he was explicitly allocating the array, I assumed that that was his purpose. Anyway, even if he needs the count afterwards, it can be easily queried from `std::vector`'s `size()` member. No need to bother the user with it.

Comment: @JorenHeit I agree with you, I was not expecting to debate on proper user input. I was simply pointing out that as it stands, he still needs `n` for the loop, not just vector size.

Comment: Just a point of contention:  There is no need for the hand-written loop to print the contents - `std::copy` works nicely for that.

Comment: @ZacHowland You're totally right, but as he said he's new to C++, I doubt that's a good idea.

Comment: @faranwath That is exactly why it **is** a good idea.  Better to learn good habits to start with than to develop bad habits and have to unlearn them later.

Comment: @ZacHowland And why is a `for` loop a bad habit? Does he need to learn *right now* what an iterator is?

Comment: @faranwath http://www.drdobbs.com/stl-algorithms-vs-hand-written-loops/184401446 - and yes.  Since he is dealing with pointers, it is a great time to introduce iterators.

Comment: @ZacHowland OK, it's not wise to start a discussion for such a small thing. Let him choose...

Comment: Expecting the user to Ctrl+d to end input is ludicrous. It should just accept an empty input as being done.

Answer (score 2):

[Example 1](http://ideone.com/HgkNCf)

```
int main()
{
    int* x = NULL;
    int n, numbers;
    std::cin >> n;
    x = new int[n]; // need a semi-colon here
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        std::cin >> numbers;
        x[i] = numbers;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        std::cout << "x[" << j << "] = " << x[j] << std::endl;
    }

    delete [] x; // you mean x, not a

    return 0;
}
```

Once you fix (what I assume are just typos), what you have works fine.  However, unless this is for an assignment, you should consider using `std::vector` instead of raw dynamic memory allocation.  Doing so would reduce your code to about 4 lines.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> myvector;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<int>(), std::back_inserter(myvector));
    std::copy(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

or, in [C++11](http://ideone.com/yBjpuj)

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> myvector{std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),  std::istream_iterator<int>()};
    std::copy(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in the first for loop can we have the following code,
"for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
        std::cin >>  x[i];
 }''

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create the array dynamically? This way, the user won't have to type in the number of elements in advance:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec;
    int x;
    while (cin >> x)
        vec.push_back(x);

    for (int y: vec)
        cout << y << ' ';
    cout << '\n';
}
```

The `cout` statements are just to illustrate that everything worked.